# Why does my button if statement stop parts of my code from running on Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a code that will ask for a password if a button is pressed. Before I added the if statement for the button, the code works, as soon as I put in the if the button is pressed statement, it only runs the first part of the loop. my code is below.(Arduino)
I only posted the first part to keep it short.

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const int rs = 7, en = 6, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);
const int button = 13;
int buttonState = 0;
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {  //define the symbols on the buttons of the keypads
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {39, 41, 43, 45}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {47, 49, 51, 53}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap (hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
byte value = 0;  // Will not go above 255 using byte identifier
char customKey = 0;
#define Password_Length 4
char digits[Password_Length];
char password1[Password_Length] = "700";
char password2[Password_Length] = "316";
char password3[Password_Length] = "279";
byte digits_count = 0, password_count = 0;
int pos = 0;
bool password;
char key;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  customKey = customKeypad.getKey(); 
  if (customKey == '#') {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("  Door is close");
    delay(3000);
  }
} else Open();
}

void clearData() {
  while (digits_count != 0) {  // This can be used for any array size,
   digits[digits_count--] = 0; //clear array for new data
  }
  return;
}

void Open() {
 buttonState = digitalRead(button);
 if (buttonState == LOW){
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
   lcd.print(" Enter Password:");
   customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
   if (customKey) { // makes sure a key is actually pressed, equal to (customKey != NO_KEY)
     digits[digits_count] = customKey; // store char into data array
     lcd.setCursor(digits_count, 1); // move cursor to show each new char
     lcd.print(digits[digits_count]); // print char at said cursor
     digits_count++; // increment data array by 1 to store new char, also keep track of the number of chars entered
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `Open()` func, you are checking the button only once and at a very specific moment. You might want to check it during a certain amount of time in this function, if this button needs to be pressed.

Also, note that your `loop()` is ending before the `else Open()` but that might be an error when copying the code here as this should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using a Finite State Machine (FSM) approach to solve your problem. Nick Gammon has an excellent [guide](https://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine) on how FSMs work and what they can do for you. As Tom already mentioned, your routine for checking the button might be too short.

I would rather trigger a flag once you detect the key "#" and call a new "state" on the machine that would be in charge of processing the buttons. This way, you will basically leave your loop() partially empty and only polling for a key pressed.

Basically, you need to enumerate a group of states where one of them could be READ_KEY and another one might be ACCESS_GRANTED...and so on and so forth.

Best wishes

dzalf